# How to get Local Notification when UISwitch is on?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a beginner of iOS development. I'm now developing a battery utility app in my university project. In my Settings column, I have an option to let user to turn on or off for whether you want to get a notification when the battery is fully charged. I've a problem of getting local notification when the switch is on. I only get an alert view when I tried to turn off the switch and turn it on back when the battery level == 1.0. Appreciate if someone could help me with this. :)

Here's my codes:

-(void)notifySwitched
{

```
if([self.notifyFullyChargedSwitch isOn])
{
    float batterylevel = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel;

    [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryMonitoringEnabled = YES;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryLevelChanged:) name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    [self notifyFullyCharged];
}
```

}

-(void)notifyFullyCharged{

```
float batterylevel = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel;

if(batterylevel == 1.0){

    // Schedule the notification
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    //localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Unplug your device. Your battery has been fully charged.";
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Slide to view";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The code actually adds observer only when the switch is turned ON for the first time. Moving the following code to any initialise method example:- ViewDownload, should add the observer irrespective of switch state.

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryMonitoringEnabled = YES;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryLevelChanged:) name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Then in the batteryLevelChanged method, the switch state condition needs to be checked before showing the alert.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Now, I did received a notification by showing me an alert view only when I get returned to my app. However, it couldn't notify me when the application is in inactive state, I didn't receive any notification in the notification center, means that when the phone is locked. :(